# Could not create an acl object: Role '9' - how to resolve this?

Tags: backend, acl, create, role

Something like this happend when I'm trying to login to backend:

> {"0":"Could not create an acl object: Role '9' not found","1":"#0 
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()\n#1
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(227):
>   Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()\n#2
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(102):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()\n#3
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(159):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->processLogin()\n#4
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('helpa_user', 'czarymamy1')\n#5
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login',
>   Array)\n#6
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('helpa_user',
>   'czarymamy1')\n#7
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login',
>   Array, Array)\n#8
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('helpa_user',
>   'czarymamy1')\n#9
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#13
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#14
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#17
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#18
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#19
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#20
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#21
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#22
>   /var/www/html/MAGENTO_HELPA/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#23
>   {main}","url":"/MAGENTO_HELPA/administrator/admin/index/index/key/feca50169fe7c3c42899965d7294f05a432197c786d63c62a2065e2ae579b627/","script_name":"/MAGENTO_HELPA/index.php"}

can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

That issue of Magento Cache when loading rule collection from the database

> Just Clean Magento Cache.

Comment: This is correct answer, thanks! You know you are dealing with crappy software when this happens.